# Do polygon pours have to be either ground or supply voltage?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, pour

I was wondering if it is possible to have polygon pours but not connected to anything. Will that affect the circuit in some manner ?

Because for the pcb I'm designing, if I use polygon pours as ground planes it results in a large number of isolated islands.

[image]
So is it better to send the pcb design off without any polygons or is it ok to send it with non-connected polygon pours?

Many Thanks

Comment: thank u but that doesn't really answer my question :)

Comment: I think this question is better worded "Is it better to have no ground plane, or a ground plane cut to pieces?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. First you can turn off orphaned polygons (in the properties of the polygon after it's placed un-check orphans). Second you can punch VIAs into the areas that are orphaned connecting them to ground. (I'm assuming your using Eagle).

There may be issues with orphaned pours if you are using high speed signals near them because they may tend to couple into them but otherwise there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: So is option one valid when I'm not using the polygon as ground or power ?

Comment: Yes, by turning off orphans eagle will not place any pour when that pour cannot be connected to the Net of it's polygon.

Answer (score 2):

I've never designed a PCB where unconnected pour islands could not be got rid of (I've designed dozens and dozens, maybe 200 in many years) and I always connect a pour to ground if not needed for anything else. Consider re-routing some tracks to allow unconnected pours to naturally flood to each other. Copper balance is important. If copper balance is deemed not to be important and a pour is not needed then don't flood that layer but, in my experience, it is useful to have another ground plane. There will be exceptions of course.

Maybe show a small section of your PCB so that specific recommendations can be made.

Comment: It's a pretty bad earth plane even for a double sided board. I'd concentrate on minimal tracking on ground plane layer and, if that means vias up and down on certain tracks quite a few times then so be it. Performance comes before cost of a couple of dozen more vias. It also looks like you have some clearance problems too.

Comment: Those little islands, although trivial electrically are probably disabled by a setting in the CAD package you use as per what vini_i said in his comment. Also check what pour clearances are when flooding - it looks quite tight.